# What's a word for "a thoroughly enjoyable experience"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

What's a word for "a thoroughly enjoyable experience"? Something like the opposite of a "trial"?

Comment: Can you please also include a sentence example where you would use this word? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 10):

A **pleasure**?

> The condition or sensation induced by the experience or anticipation of what is felt to be good or desirable; a feeling of happy satisfaction or enjoyment; delight, gratification. Opposed to pain.

A **treat**?

> Something highly enjoyable; a great pleasure, delight, or gratification.

A **delight**?

> Anything in which one takes delight, or which affords delight; an object of delight; a source of great pleasure or joy.

(All from the OED.)

Answer (score 2):

"Slang" terms that I've come across for "pleasurable" are "lark," and "lulu."'

That was a lark. or
That was a lulu.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something that gives pleasure:
[*Delight*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delight)

> a high degree of gratification : joy; also : extreme satisfaction
>
> something that gives great pleasure

If you're talking about the state of mind:
[*Bliss*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bliss)

> complete happiness

There are also *joy* (which can be used in both contexts), *pleasure*, and [*felicity*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/felicity).

Answer (score 1):

A good opposite of *trial* would be *lark* or *breeze*, if you are interested in the testing or "putting to the proof" aspect of the word *trial*.

> How was the job interview? It was a *breeze*.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a [ball](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Ball)  (sense 2).

Answer (score 1):

How about 'I'm having **a blast**!'?

Answer (score 0):

When you're having a really hard time it can feel like a *trial*. When you're having a really good time it can feel like a *[festival.](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=define+%3a+festival&pbx=1&oq=define+%3a+festival&aq=f&aqi=g2g-v2&aql=1&gs_sm=s&gs_upl=0l0l5l2049l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=1cd3f9be41483c89&biw=1024&bih=581)*